# Specify parent in API request

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm pretty new to ember and have been somewhat thrown in at the deep end with it so there's a good chance I'm missing something that should be incredibly obvious here.

Anyway, my rails application has defined a route as `/api/1/publications/:publication_id/catalogs`. This is working fine.

However, I cannot for the life of me get Ember to use this route, everything I try either results in a request to `/api/1/catalogs` - or no request at all.

My router.js file has:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('publication', { path: '/publication/:publication_id' }, function() {
    this.route('catalogs', { path: '/publication/:publication_id/catalogs' });
  });
});
```

My publications model has

```
catalogs: DS.hasMany('catalog'),
```

My catalog model has

```
publication: DS.belongsTo('publication')
```

And, amongst a few others lost to undo's, I have tried the following methods of querying this data in my route .js file

```
model() {
  this.modelFor('publication.name')
  var output = {
    model: this.modelFor("publication")
  };

  let publication = this.modelFor('publication');
  output.catalogs = publication.get('catalogs');

  return RSVP.hash(output);
},
```

...

```
output.catalogs = output.model.get('/api/ember/1/publications/' + output.model.id + '/catalogs');
```

...

```
var output = {
  model: this.modelFor("publication"),
  catalogs: model.catalogs,
```

...

```
this.get('store').findAll('catalog', {'publication_id': output.model.id, reload: true});
```

Could someone please give me a pointer to what I'm doing wrong / not doing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right you are trying to customize the URL used to query `has-many` relationship `catalogs` of a `publication`. Ember Data uses Adapter to configure API endpoints. I guess your application uses [`DS.RESTAdapter`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.RESTAdapter). If so, you should implement a custom [`urlForFindHasMany` method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.RESTAdapter/methods/urlForFindHasMany?anchor=urlForFindHasMany). Assuming the Adapter is correctly configured to fetch `publication` it may look like the following:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  urlForFindHasMany(id, modelName, snapshot) {
    let baseUrl = this.buildURL(modelName, id);
    return `${baseUrl}/catalogs`;
  }
});
```

The relationship should be queried via property on `publication` model:

```
async model() {
  let publication = await this.store.findRecord('publication', '1');
  return publication.catalogs;
},
```

The `catalogs` property is a [`DS.PromiseManyArray`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.PromiseManyArray), a special object that acts as as an `Ember.Array` and a Promise at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Your router looks a bit odd. Here is what it normally looks like in v3+

```
this.route('products', function() {
    this.route('show', { path: ‘/:id’ }, function() {
      this.route('show-detail');
    });
```

Here we have 3 routes: /products (selection screen), /products/1/show  and products/1/show/show-detail.

Also, in case you do not have it, the [Ember inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi) chrome add-on is great at helping determine what routes/ controllers. etc the Ember app is using and recognizing

Comment: I'm not sure I should have even mentioned the routes - that was created by me just trying to make something - anything - stick; removing the route entirely makes me no closer or further than my current position. The point of all this is simply trying to get a collection of catalogs to interact with.

Comment: I see, so you cannot get data from the store then? Assuming your store is properly configured (you can get data for other routes), the you should be able to use store.find, store,findAll or store.query. You can find the doc here: [link](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/finding-records/)

Comment: I cannae get data from the store - but can from other routes. I can see it *trying* to get data from the store when I check the console, but its not including the parent URL structure in the request it makes to the API